# Can't reach some https sites using Chrome but Firefox works fine

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, https

I've installed Chrome (not Chromium) on Ubuntu laptop and can't get to some sites that use https. Firefox works fine.

In Chrome I get:

```
     This page not available
     ERR_FAILED

     The webpage at https://some.site.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

Since it works fine in Firefox I know the server is not down and has not moved.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall a friend having a problem similar to this.  The solution we used was to flush out the secure sites certificates and cache.  I'm not sure exactly how to do this in Chrome, but it is likely under advanced settings.